# Showing that $\left(1-2p^{2}\sin^2{\omega}\right)^2 + p^{2}\sin^{2} w\leq 1$ implies $4p^2 \leq 4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

If $\xi = 1-2p^{2}\sin^{2} \omega -ip\sin w$, then the modulus of $\xi$ is

$$|\xi|^{2} = \left(1-2p^{2}\sin^2{\omega}\right)^2 + p^{2}\sin^{2} w$$

For $|\xi|^2 \leq 1$,

$$4p^2 \leq {4\sin^2{\omega \over 2}-\sin^2\omega \over \sin^4{\omega \over 2}}= 4$$

I am not sure how to get the second line. Can anyone show me? I have expanded out the bracket, etc, but do not get this expression.

Comment: You have sufficient rep to indicate that you ought to be using mathjax within your posts, and not an uploaded image.  Please edit this post to use mathjax to express what is in the image.

Comment: Also, please show your work, after, as you claim, you expanded out the bracket.

Comment: If you're going to edit the post *for* the OP, do so correctly, @ChristianF

Comment: I had just last line in my proof so I edit only that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $$1\geq 1-4p^2\sin^2{\omega \over 2}+4p^4\sin^4{\omega \over 2}+p^2\sin^2\omega$$

we have $$0\geq p^2(-4\sin^2{\omega \over 2}+4p^2\sin^4{\omega \over 2}+\sin^2\omega)$$

so  $$0\geq -4\sin^2{\omega \over 2}+4p^2\sin^4{\omega \over 2}+\sin^2\omega$$

so $$ 4\sin^2{\omega \over 2}-\sin^2\omega\geq 4p^2\sin^4{\omega \over 2}$$

so $$ {4\sin^2{\omega \over 2}-\sin^2\omega \over \sin^4{\omega \over 2}}\geq 4p^2$$

Comment: thank you, i understand now.